# python script , how to ask the user to enter the extension file he want and make a list of existing files

Tags: python, python-2.7, search, operating-system, user-input

i have this script that select from a selected path  a selected type of files without asking the user and it work fine.

what i want is the ability to get the user input and make a list of requested type of files.

can anyone help me with this?

## fileSearch.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch
root = 'C:\PythonWorkspace'
extension = "*.py"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, extension):
            print os.path.join(path, name)
```

I wrote another script based on this one

## newFileSearch.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
from fnmatch import fnmatch

root2 = 'C:\Users'

request = raw_input("Select the extension you want!")

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root2):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch(name, request):
            print os.path.join(path.name)
```

in the second script nothing happen it just ask user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`print os.path.join(path.name)` should be `print os.path.join(path, name)` as above.

Also, if you want the user to just input the extension (for instance `py`) you can use:

`if fnmatch(name, "*." + request):`

Comment: and if i want the user to select the path isn't the same logic ?